# How to pass a multidimension array to javascript from c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, multidimensional-array

I am using a JQuery charting plugin that takes in data points using a multi-dimension array

```
    var line1 = [['23-May-2008', 1578.55], ['20-Jun-2008', 566.5], 
['25-Jul-2008', 480.88], ['22-Aug-2008', 509.84]];
```

How can I return data formatted like the above from c#? I have tried generating a string that matches the output, but it doesn't work...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Stats s in perfData)
        {          
            sb.Append("['" + String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", p.Date) + "'], " + "[" + p.Value +"],");
        }

        string data = sb.ToString();
        data += data.TrimEnd(new[] { ',' });
        data = "[" + data + "]";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `JavaScriptSerializer` from the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly:

```
        var data = perfData.Select(p => 
            new object[] { String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", p.Date), p.Value });

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
```

Comment: That seems to return the data back in the right format [["01-19-2012",2.60]], but it is throwing an Object, object exception.

Comment: Where is this exception thrown? In the client javascript code?

Comment: I was playing around with it and the output is correct. There is some other weird issue with the plugin not working with ajax data, but the exact same data works on page load...

Answer (score 4):

You can use any JSON serializer(*DataContractJsonSerializer* , *JavaScriptSerializer*) to convert your object to javascript format. But I , personally, prefer [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/).

```
List<object[]> array2D = new List<object[]>() { 
    new object[] { DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1000), 1578.55 }, 
    new object[] { DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2000), 566.5 },
    new object[] { DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3000), 480.88 },
    new object[] { DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4000), 509.84 } 
};

string jsonstr =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array2D,new MyDateTimeConvertor());


public class MyDateTimeConvertor : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DateTimeConverterBase
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not implemented yet");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ToString(@"dd-MMM-yyy"));
    }
}
```

and output is a valid javascript object

```
[["04-May-2009",1578.55],["08-Aug-2006",566.5],["12-Nov-2003",480.88],["15-Feb-2001",509.84]]
```

Comment: Would you know how to do that using the json serializer?

Comment: if what you ask is datetime formatting, no, This is why I use Json.Net since I provides a great flexibility.

Comment: @L.B I used JavascriptSerializer. While ago the it returned a proper array in jquery. But now it's only returning a set of strings and not in array format in jquery. Is there considerable difference in using JavascrtipSerializer and JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try JSON helper (JavaScript Object Notation) to do that kind of manipulation. I found that link, hope this helps http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/07/23/javascriptserializer-dictionary-to-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. shouldnt it be like below to generate what you need?
2. This is not valid JSON, so do check if your plugin is taking JSON or not, if yes then make use of JSONserializer in C#.

   ```
   foreach (Stats s in perfData)
   {          
       sb.Append("['" + String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", p.Date) +","+  p.Value +"],");
   }

   string data = sb.ToString();
   data += data.TrimEnd(new[] { ',' });
   data = "[" + data + "]";
   ```

Comment: The plugin takes in a multi-dimension array. Isn't that different than json?